# xamarin.forms error The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following constructor for the page

```
public MainPage(string name, string price)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Name.Text = name;
    Price.Text = price;
}
```

I have a name defined in the xaml file

```
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding name}" 
                                    FontSize="25" 
                                    TextColor="#305C55" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    x:Name="Name"/>
```

but i have such error :The name "Name" does not exist in the current context.
why is this happening?

Comment: is this Label contained within a template?  Why are you assigning the values directly AND using binding?  PIck one or the other.

Comment: Two possible causes: **1)** Build Solution. Intellisense doesn't know about the xaml x:Name, until you have successfully built the xaml. **2)** Is the Label inside of an `ItemTemplate`, e.g. for a ListView or CollectionView? Or any other Template?

Answer (score 0):

1.Clean your project first.

2.Rebuild it, change your XAML file properties (Build Action) from Embedded Resource to C# complier, Rebuild your project (will throw errors).

3.Switch back your XAML file properties to Embedded Resource, Rebuild.

Refer to this link: [make on button click action for first time in Xamarin (C# and xaml file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163151/make-on-button-click-action-for-first-time-in-xamarin-c-and-xaml-file)